# What is this page unresponsive error in Blazor WASM?

Tags: dom, browser, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am developing an industry-level blazor application in .NET 6. currently, it is not a simple application, because It has several assemblies and each assembly has a considerable amount of razor files classes, interfaces, etc. I am using some heavy manipulation inside the applications for the data getting and sending requests. So my issue is, currently I am getting this page unresponsive error on chrome browser. I can't load the page.

[image]

I cleared the browser cache, tried on different browsers .but they didn't work.

Does anybody know what may be the reason for this ??

Comment: when click wait , this popup disappears but after about 1 minute it comes again

Comment: I have included some heavy code inside the initialize method. actually, I am rendering the UI components dynamically inside the Oninitialized method of each razor page.

Comment: I would recommend debugging it - finding the problem and fixing it. With the information you have shared, that is my best advice.

Comment: Blazor WebAssembly is single-threaded. You are taking up too much time on that single thread somewhere.  There isn't nearly enough information here to debug it for you.

Comment: Did the app ever work?  If yes, then what code changes were made at the point it stopped?  Stepping through the git history might help identify the problem.

Comment: I tend to think like @HenkHolterman, you  are probably overloading the thread, look if there are long running operation anywhere, especially Task.Run with loops that never releases the single thread you have in Wasm.